# php date offset

Tags: php, datetime, date, time, timezone

I'm using php's `date()` function to print out a time, which is retrieved from mysql. The actual time that's printed out is always **one hour off**.

I'm calling

```
date('H:i, d M Y', 100000)
```

I'm expecting `"03:46, 02 Jan 1970"` but got `"04:46, 02 Jan 1970"` instead.

Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set timezone before, using `date_default_timezone_set()` because `date()` function depends of timezone setting (from `php.ini` or set by code)

That returns date/time according to your current timezone.

Check your actual timezone using

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

Set (change) it using

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); # UTC is just an example
```

For complete list of supported timezones in PHP [check this link](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

### Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('H:i, d M Y', 100000);
```

### Output:

> 03:46, 02 Jan 1970

Your current timezone offset is `+0100` and that's why you've got `04:46, 02 Jan 1970`. Also don't forget that back to 70's a lot of countries did not use DST rules.

### References

- [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) - Format a local time/date
- [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) - Sets the default timezone
- [date_default_timezone_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php) - Gets the default timezone
- [List of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're having a timezone issue.

You can set the timezone for your PHP app using `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`, replacing UTC to whatever you require. This should fix your problem.

For more info, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php